# Subscribing a rest api to kafka events

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I recently started working on Kafka for a project of mine.

I am trying to figure out how can I subscribe a rest API to a Kafka event rather than running a consumer which keeps on listening to the topic.

I came across Kafka connect, but not able to figure out exactly how to achieve the same.

Details: I am running a spring-boot project as a producer which uses KafkaTemplate provided by spring to publish the message. Also, the consumer is a Spring Boot project which exposes rest APIs.

Answer (score 0):

There is no other way than to use the Kafka consumer library to have data come from Kafka. Kafka Connect would do the same.

A RESTful service is stateless. Having a consumer is more stateful (offset maintenance, for example).

If you want *streaming events* in general, maybe you could look into WebSockets or gRPC instead.

Comment: I was thinking more of altering the sinkConnector in order to sonsume data from kafka server and then send it to the respective API's. Can this be achieved?

If yes, how do I get started?

Comment: Altering which Sink Connector? The SinkConnector class is only an interface, so if you want to start somewhere, then start with implementing that.

Comment: Or you can use an existing one - See example config here https://github.com/llofberg/kafka-connect-rest/blob/master/examples/spring/config/sink.json, but if possible, it would be better to include the Kafka consumer inside the API. Otherwise, you are slamming your HTTP API with constant requests for every Kafka event. My point is that consuming from Kafka is less overhead than HTTP network traffic